# How to create a boundary around transmission lines?

Tags: qgis, buffer, qgis-processing, qgis-2

New to QGIS and GIS in general.  I'm using QGIS 2.18 and I've downloaded the shapefile from here https://hifld-geoplatform.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/electric-power-transmission-lines.  I set up a query to display only the transmission lines in my region.

How can I create a 1/2 mile boundary (polygon?) around the transmission lines?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are working in a suitable [coordinate system](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/coordinate_reference_systems.html) and create a buffer of your desired size. The result will be something like this:

[image: line buffer in QGIS]

If you are new to GIS, it would be very useful to read the official QGIS documentation for the buffer tool [here](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=buffer#buffer).

Comment: The buffer tool uses the same units as the coordinate system of the layer. If your region is in the US, and is no larger than a state, use the local NAD83 State Plane (ftUS) coordinate system. "ftUS" means its units are in US feet, so make your buffer amount 2640 for a half mile buffer.

Comment: I tried setting my vector layer from the shapefile to the NAD83 Tennessee (ftUS) and it disappears.  It's default CRS is EPSG:4326, WGS 84.

Comment: Try exporting the dataset with the desired projection and then use the buffer tool.

Comment: Tried to export and I get "Export to vector file failed.
Error: Cannot overwrite a OGR layer in place"

Comment: Never mind.  I got it.

Comment: If the answer helped, please mark it as accepted.